Esp-32 and LoRa ra-02 - send and receive loop not working
I have two sets of ESP-32 and Ra-02 LoRa module. I want to send a message from one node to the other and get the reply acknowledgement back.
Sending a message from node1 reaches node2. But the reply from node2 to node1 is not happening. Am I missing something here.
Node1 code:
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

#define SCK 18
#define MISO 19
#define MOSI 23
#define NSS 5
#define RESET 14
#define DIO0 26

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);

  LoRa.setPins(NSS, RESET, DIO0);
  if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }

  Serial.println("LoRa Transmitter");
}

void loop() {
  String message = "Hello";
  Serial.print("Sending: ");
  Serial.println(message);
  
  LoRa.beginPacket();
  LoRa.print(message);
  LoRa.endPacket();

  delay(100);

  // Wait for acknowledgment
  unsigned long startMillis = millis();
  unsigned long timeout = 2000; // 2 seconds timeout
  String response = "";

  LoRa.idle(); // Ensure the module is in idle state before entering the loop
  while (millis() - startMillis < timeout) {
    int packetSize = LoRa.parsePacket();
    if (packetSize) {
      while (LoRa.available()) {
        response += (char)LoRa.read();
      }
      break; // Exit the loop once a packet is received
    }
  }

  if (response != "") {
    Serial.print("Received response: ");
    Serial.println(response);
  } else {
    Serial.println("No response received");
  }

  delay(5000);
}

Node2 code:
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

#define SCK 18
#define MISO 19
#define MOSI 23
#define NSS 5
#define RESET 14
#define DIO0 26

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);

  LoRa.setPins(NSS, RESET, DIO0);
  if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }

  Serial.println("LoRa Receiver");
}

void loop() {
  int packetSize = LoRa.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize) {
    String incoming = "";
    while (LoRa.available()) {
      incoming += (char)LoRa.read();
    }

    Serial.print("Received: ");
    Serial.println(incoming);

    // Send acknowledgment
    String response = incoming + ":ack";
    Serial.print("Sending: ");
    Serial.println(response);
    
    LoRa.beginPacket();
    LoRa.print(response);
    LoRa.endPacket();
  }
}



How does each side know whether it is a transmitter or receiver?  The code is identical.

@TimRoberts, I don't know what is the problem, but the codes aren't identical.

Check here for an example of how to do send and receive at the same time:  https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-LoRa/blob/master/examples/LoRaDuplexCallback/LoRaDuplexCallback.ino

lora.idle() in node1 makes sure you will never receive anything, ever. It doesn't do what you think it does... It basically asks the LoRa module to ignore everything...
Your code, overall, is not very good. In your loop you should have:

A time counter that checks against elapsed milliseconds to decide whether ti send another packet.

Code that checks whether there's an incoming LoRapacket, and if so displays it.


Don't use delay() in loop()...

I did couple of modifications and I am able to get a reply back from the Receiver.
Node1 code:
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

#define SS      5
#define RST     14
#define DIO0    26

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);

  LoRa.setPins(SS, RST, DIO0);

  if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }

  Serial.println("LoRa Initialized");

  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Sending message: ");
  LoRa.beginPacket();
  LoRa.print("message");
  LoRa.endPacket();

  // Wait for an acknowledgment
  long startMillis = millis();
  String ack = "";
  while (millis() - startMillis < 1000) {
    int packetSize = LoRa.parsePacket();
    if (packetSize) {
      while (LoRa.available()) {
        ack += (char)LoRa.read();
      }
      break;
    }
  }

  Serial.println("ACK: " + ack);
  delay(5000); // Send message every 5 seconds
}

Node2 Code:
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

#define SS 5
#define RST 14
#define DIO0 26

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial)
    ;

  LoRa.setPins(SS, RST, DIO0);

  if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1)
      ;
  }

  Serial.println("LoRa Initialized");
}

void loop() {
  int packetSize = LoRa.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize) {
    String received = "";
    String reply = "";
    while (LoRa.available()) {
      received += (char)LoRa.read();
    }
    Serial.println("Received: "+ received);
    reply = received + ":ack";
    
    LoRa.beginPacket();
    LoRa.print(reply);
    LoRa.endPacket();
    Serial.println("Sent: "+ reply);
  }
}

